# Does the Cleric's Channel Energy ability heal living enemies too?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, cleric, healing

From the description of the Pathfinder Cleric's [Channel Energy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric#TOC-Channel-Energy-Su-) ability it seems that it will heal damage to enemies as well as allies. Is this correct or is the healing applied to only the cleric's friends?

> Channeling energy causes a burst that affects **all creatures** of one type (either undead or living) in a 30-foot radius centered on the cleric. The amount of damage dealt or healed is equal to 1d6 points of damage plus 1d6 points of damage for every two cleric levels beyond 1st (2d6 at 3rd, 3d6 at 5th, and so on). Creatures that take damage from channeled energy receive a Will save to halve the damage. The DC of this save is equal to 10 + 1/2 the cleric's level + the cleric's Charisma modifier. Creatures healed by channel energy cannot exceed their maximum hit point total—all excess healing is lost. A cleric may channel energy a number of times per day equal to 3 + her Charisma modifier. This is a standard action that does not provoke an attack of opportunity. A cleric can choose whether or not to include herself in this effect.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Yes** as it states *all creatures* of one type are effected.

To target selectively a cleric should select the [Selective Channeling](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/feats.html#_selective-channeling) feat which allows them to exclude targets up to their charisma modifier from the effect.

Clerics can also modify who they target using the [Alignment channel](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/feats.html#_alignment-channel) feat to target outsiders instead.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know of the Selective Channeling feat. Sounds like a good thing to have.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. To exclude certain creatures of the concerned type from the channeling effect, you'd have to have the [Selective Channeling](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/selective-channeling---final) feat.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes.**

Since the description of the ability doesn't mention allies or enemies specifically, it heals living enemies and harms allied undead.